# inconsistent equality of signed and unsigned after overflow in C

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned, integer-overflow, short

I'm trying to test equality of signed and unsigned versions of short, int, and long in C. In particular, I have used the following test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    signed short ss = 0x8000; // 2^15
    unsigned short us = 0x8000;
    printf("ss = %i, us = %i\n", ss, us);
    if (ss == us) { printf("ss == us\n"); }
    else { printf("ss != us\n"); }

    signed int si = 0x80000000; // 2^31
    unsigned int ui = 0x80000000;
    printf("si = %i, ui = %i\n", si, ui);
    if (si == ui) { printf("si == ui\n"); }
    else { printf("si != ui\n"); }

    signed long sl = 0x8000000000000000L; // 2^63
    unsigned long ul = 0x8000000000000000UL; // 2^63
    printf("sl = %li, ul = %lu\n", sl, ul);
    if (sl == ul) { printf("si == ui\n"); }
    else { printf("sl != ul\n"); }
}
```

The code outputs the following:

```
ss = -32768, us = 32768
ss != us
si = -2147483648, ui = -2147483648
si == ui
sl = -9223372036854775808, ul = 9223372036854775808
si == ui
```

So for shorts they are not equal, but for the other two they are. Is there something wrong with what I am assuming, or is this just a known quirk of C?

Comment: That is not a quirk, but standard behaviour.

Comment: You are not comparing like for like in the `printf` statements: in the first two (but not the third example) you use `%i` (signed int) for both the signed and unsigned values, which print the data that was placed on the stack as it is told to. Once there, there is no way to tell if they are signed or unsigned apart from their context. In the case of the `short`, the values are promoted to `signed int` and `unsigned int` (because of the variable type) before placing on the stack, and are then printed as `signed int` because of the `%i` specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your output, the `short` and `unsigned short` are smaller than `int`.  Both get converted to `int` for the first comparison and the converted values differ.

For `int` and `unsigned int`, the comparison is performed as `unsigned int`. The conversion gives the same value and the comparison is true.  Note that you should print the numbers with an appropriate format: `printf("si = %i, ui = %u\n", si, ui);`

For the `long` and `unsigned long` test, your computer seems to have 64 bit longs, the comparison is performed as `unsigned long`, the `long` value is converted to an `unsigned long` but has the same representation, to comparison is true again.

Note that you should not store numbers larger than the maximum value into a signed type:

`signed short ss = 0x8000;` is not guaranteed to store `-32768` to `ss`.

Same problem for `signed int si = 0x80000000;` and `signed long sl = 0x8000000000000000L;`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that in your compiler, both `short` and `unsigned short` can be converted to `int` without loss of information; their comparison is done after the conversion ("promotion").

The promotions are explained in the section [Usual Arithmetic Conversions](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) at  securecoding.cert.org

1. If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is
   needed.
2. If both operands are of the same integer type (signed or
   unsigned), the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion
   rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
3. If
   the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or
   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with
   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with
   unsigned integer type.
4. If the type of the operand with signed
   integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the
   operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned
   integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed
   integer type.
5. Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned
   integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
   integer type.